# Does Polars support UUID?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

I have a time series of string-formatted UUIDs, and I would like Polars to translate them into u128 numbers for better storage and querying.

Similar to what we do with dates:

```
....str.strptime(pl.Datetime, fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ", strict=False)
```

Is this supported, or do I need to handle it on the Python side?

Also, I don't see a `u128` type, but there's a `Decimal` that seems to be an `i128`. If I were to do my own translation, which type should I use?

P.S. I notice a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7175) in the Polars repository about supporting the Rust crate `Uuid`, but in a way, this could be implemented without it. So, I am not sure if it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polars doesn't support a `u128` dtype. If you can accept the loss, you can store them as `u64` or otherwise as a `Utf8` column.

We haven't support for this yet, but we will also get `FixedSizeBinary` in the future which could also fit this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and insights into the roadmap. Having `u128` support with `str::strpuuid` would be fantastic. However, if that's not feasible, `FixedSizeBinary` would be a welcome alternative. Our use case involves server request logs with a request UUID on each line, which is needed for correlation.

Comment: @ritchie46 - in python, how would I extract a UUID to pandas via FixedSizeBinary?